# Shell script get filename of file, dragged to script

Tags: macos, shell, batch-file

I've been trying to solve this problem for about 4 hours.

I created a windows .bat file which, by dragging a file on it, takes care of copying it into a directory and then opening the copied file.

I'm trying to do the usual thing on mac os x but unfortunately it does not work.

I created a script script converted to .app, which opens firefox browser when opened. Everything works.

The problem occurs when I go to my file, a simple .xml, and I say to open it with my .app created, or just drag the file on the app.
Of course the browser will open, but I need to open firefox, the open URL is the path of the file dragged.

I've tried all the possible $0 $1 etc but I get the path of my script script inside the .app archive and not the file path dragged over the app.

WINDOWS

```
@echo off
Title TEST
Mode con cols=90 lines=5

COPY /D "%~1" "C:\PA\" 

IF [%1] EQU [] Goto:Error
CD /D "%~1">nul 2>&1 && Goto:Explorer_Folder || Goto :OpenFile
Exit /b


:OpenFile <File>
Start "Drag and Drop" "firefox.exe" "C:\PA\%~nx1"
Exit /b


:Explorer_Folder <Folder>
Explorer "%~1"
Exit /b


:Error
Color 0F & echo(
ECHO error
Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak >nul
Exit /b
```

OS X

```
#!/bin/bash
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
open -a Firefox $BASEDIR
```

This open firefox, but open it with the directory of my .app

Thanks to all

Comment: Questions regarding \[macos\] may be better asked on the relevant stackexchange site, which has a Q&A on this topic [how-do-i-make-a-bash-script-so-that-i-can-drag-its-input-on-top-of-the-icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91285/how-do-i-make-a-bash-script-so-that-i-can-drag-its-input-on-top-of-the-icon)

Comment: I think you need to start with an Automator script which can then run your bash script. I think the key is to have `on run{input,parameters}` which allows you to get the names of what was dropped on your app, you can then call `do shell script XYZ` to do whatever your app was originally going to do. Example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820104/2836621

Answer (score 0):

For the OS X version, did you try this?
(it should open your argument file with Firefox)

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Firefox $1
```

Comment: This work yes, but open firefox with in the url the directory where my application.app is located. I want if i drag and drop a file into the application.app open firefox and show the directory of file dragged.
For example, if file is an xml, i drag it into the application.app, firefox popup and show my xml dropped, where the link is the path of the file